# devolver cadena usando un metodo y con valores de un HashMap

Tags: hashmap

Estoy haciendo un diccionario con hashmap en java y necesito hacer un metodo que me devuelva la frase la traduccion de (Esta es la clave "Palabra en español") es = ("Palabra en ingles" este es el valor)

```
public String translate(){

        for (Map.Entry<String,String>i:dictionary.entrySet()){
            return("La traducción de " + i.getKey() + " es = " + i.getValue());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

tengo esto
es un metodo en una sola clase por eso sin parametros pero solo me arroja el primer valor y la primera clave y necesito que me arroje esa frase con todos los valores y clave de manera que quede algo asi:

```
la traduccion de rojo es = red
la traduccion de azul es = blue
la traduccion de amarillo es = yellow
la traduccion de verde es = green
```

pero no se como hacerlo, si me pueden decir como se los agradeceria, no se puede usar un `system.out.print` directo en un metodo dice mi profesor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te interesa devolver el String con todas las traducciones, puedes ponerlas todas en un solo String usando, para mayor eficiencia un StringBuilder:

```java
    public String translate() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> i : dictionary.entrySet()) {
            builder.append( "La traducción de " + i.getKey() + " es = " + i.getValue() + "\n" );
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

Si prefieres no usar StringBuilder:

```java
public String translate() {
        String str = "";

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> i : dictionary.entrySet()) {
            str += "La traducción de " + i.getKey() + " es = " + i.getValue() + "\n";
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Si tu objetivo es simplemente imprimir:

```java
    public void translate() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> i : dictionary.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println( "La traducción de " + i.getKey() + " es = " + i.getValue() );
        }
    }
```

Alternativamente usando streams():

```java
public String translate() {
    return dictionary.entrySet().stream()
            .map( i ->  "La traducción de " + i.getKey() + " es = " + i.getValue() )
            .collect( Collectors.joining("\n") );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes hacer es cargar tus valores al HashMap algo asi:

```
Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
    dictionary.put("rojo","red");
    dictionary.put("azul","blue");
...
```

Ahora puedes realizar tu método, quedaría algo así:

```
public String translate(){
 Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
        dictionary.put("rojo","red");
        dictionary.put("azul","blue");
    ...//carga todos lo valore necesarios

        for (Map.Entry<String,String>i:dictionary.entrySet()){
            return("La traducción de " + i.getKey() + " es = " + i.getValue());
        }
        return "";
    }
```